# Difference of function(javascript) vs scope.function(angular function) defined in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, angularjs-controller, difference

I want to know the difference between declaration of this two function in angular controller

```
function demo() {                           
};               

scope.demo = function() {                    
};
```

Whether this two function are similar in performance or not?,Which one is the better option?

I know only one difference that watch can be applied to a function which is in the scope means angular directive or element can't call javascript function.

Comment: @LiviuM. That is not the same. function demo() is not the same as this.demo = function(). function demo() as the OP writes is a private function, and will never be accessible on the scope.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the following controller:

```
app.controller('Home', function($scope){
    function thisIsAPrivateMethod(){
      alert('Hello world');
    }

    $scope.thisIsAPublicScopedMethod(){
       alert("I'm shown!");
    }

    thisIsAPrivateMethod(); // will trigger the alert everytime HomeController is instansiated
});
```

in the view:

```
<div ng-controller="Home">
    <button ng-click="thisIsAPrivateMethod()">I will not work</button>
<button ng-click="thisIsAPublicScopedMethod()">I should display an alert</button>
</div>
```

As you see, the private method is only accessible within the controller code itself.

Comment: Here you have called private method with angular directive "ng-click" so angular will find that private method in angular scope but It is not registered in scope so it will not be called.Am I correct?

Comment: Not exactly. The first button will fail with a Javascript error, because the function does not exist outside the controller.

Comment: @SatyamKoyani Please remember to mark an answer as correct

Answer (score 1):

I think the only difference is the visibility of the function. The first one will be global, and the second one can only referred through a angular `scope` variable.